# Is "Would buy" a Past Simple Tense form?

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs

Source: [www.financemagnates.com/forex/analysis/skrill-bought-by-rival-payments-provider-neteller-for-e1-1-billion/](http://www.financemagnates.com/forex/analysis/skrill-bought-by-rival-payments-provider-neteller-for-e1-1-billion/)

> **Skrill *Bought* by Rival Payments Provider Neteller for €1.1 Billion**
>
> Optimal Payments Plc (LSE: OPAY), the group behind the popular
> NETELLER payment solution, has just revealed it *would buy* rival
> Skrill Group (Sentinel Topco Ltd) for a sum of about 1.1 billion euros
> in order to expand its online services.

In the above news the headline says "Skrill bought .." which means it is in the Past Simple Tense so I think "whoud buy" is also a Past Simple Tense (not just for express intention or whatever.)

Am I right? Could we use this form "Would + V" to indicate the Past Simple Tense? Why the writer did not just say "bought" instead? Thank you

Comment: You are right. The headline implies that Skrill has been bought already, but the next sentence says, in effect, that NETELLER **will** buy the company. The writer wasn't careful enough. The headline could have said "Skrill to be bought by..."

Comment: Not picking fault, but in the headline, you said 'bought' in your question you quote 'brought'. It may be a typo, but some people do say 'I brought a new car' - wrongly. The two words have different meanings.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, Thank you, I got it. Maybe the writter's way to attract the reader.